# Unfair coins at South Park Elementary v2

Tags: mathematics, probability, coin-tossing

Following [Unfair coins at South Park Elementary](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/unfair-coins-at-south-park-elementary)

Wendy and Sally have another friend, called Timmy. Although Timmy **has no coin**, he wants to play this game in a fair condition with them. Wendy does the first coin flip then Sally does. Is it possible to play this game in a fair way for Timmy, even without him having a coin? If so, what should be the values of $p_1$ (Wendy's coin shows head probability) and $p_2$ (Sally's Head probability) that make this game a fair game for all of them?

**Note:** Timmy cannot use Sally's or Wendy's coin and one of them wins at the end!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As Timmy has a "head" on his shoulders with probability of 1, he always wins at his turn. Then

> Wendy = 1/3 and Sally = 1/2 makes the game fair.

Comment: JonTheMon: What I wanted to write overlapped so much with your solution that I did not want to post another solution.  If you do not like my changes, then please accept my apologies and rollback.

Comment: @Gamow Oh dear, the puns. I cringed at it, but it also amused me a lot, so it stands!

Comment: Flip.  Flip. "TIMMY!"

Answer (score 6):

Unless I'm missing something

> Because Tim has no coin, he can't possibly have an outcome of "heads", therefore his winning chance is always 0.

This means

> Wendy and Sally must also have a winning chance of 0 so $p_1 = p_2 = 0$

Comment: Actually you found a solution where noone has chance to win or lose... Please assume that one of them wins every time they play this game so I cannot accept this answer :(

Answer (score 6):

Yes, we can have a game in which

> $p_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and  $p_2 =\frac{1}{2}$

So,

> We have two tosses, one each from Wendy and Sally.

And

> After two turns, the number of heads(with proper ordering) is counted by Timmy.

Thus,

> 0 heads means Wendy wins, 1 heads (on Sally's coin only) means Sally wins and 2 heads means Timmy wins. Here, each case has probability $\frac{1}{4}.$

Assuming that the results from two coins tosses are independent.

> In case of $\{Head, Tail\} $, i.e. Head on Wendy's coin and then Tail on Sally's coin, then we redo the whole two-step process!

In simple words,

> $\{Tail, Tail\} =$ Wendy wins.
>  $\{Tail, Head\} =$ Sally wins.
>  $\{Head, Head\} =$ Timmy wins.
>  $\{Head, Tail\} =$ Again two coins are tossed in the same order( Wendy then Sally)

Thus, there's no need of biased coins.

Comment: Why downvoted, please explain!

Comment: I've retracted my downvote, since when it was given there was no mention of a loop. I do think that since there is a chance of an infinite loop, this doesn't  satisfy "one of them wins at the end"

Comment: Yes, you do have a valid argument.

Comment: I think you have typo in your summary at the end

Comment: @ABcDexter try to check their chances, For example, according to your result, Wendy has a chance to get head 50%, that means when she flips she also has 50% chance not to get head. In that case Sally has 50% chance to get head, so Sally's chance to get head is actually (50%)x(50%) = 25% to get head in total because Sally does not flip coin while Wendy gets head, so you cannot add that probability in your  calculation.

Comment: @Oray do you want the game to finish at the first heads? Then your point is correct.

Comment: @ABcDexter of course, that's why there is an order for flipping the coin.

Answer (score 2):

> There are 3 kids so for this to be fair, each of them should have the
>  change 1/3.
>  So Wendy goes first then p1 = 1/3.
>  Sally goes second.
>  so Her chance is 2/3 * p2 = 1/3. This results in p2 = 1/2.
>  And "Timmah" wins if neither Wendy or Sally's coins turn out to be Head.

Answer (score 0):

If Wendy wins with probability $\dfrac1{p_1}$, then Sally's coin must be $p_2=\dfrac1{p_1-1}$, as [Xnor points out](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/unfair-coins-at-south-park-elementary).

> Any of these values will work, as they agree to split their winnings with Timmy in a $2:1$ ratio.